# Why are heights of some UI components smaller than usual?

Tags: sapui5

I have created two apps and both has the same content.
**App 1** is created with Flexbile Column Layout:
[image]

**App 2** without:
[image]

As you recognized, UI components on App 2 are bigger than on App 1.

I am using the same controls on both:

```xml
<Page id="page" title="{i18n>title}">
  <FlexBox alignItems="Start" justifyContent="Center">
    <l:Grid containerQuery="true" defaultSpan="XL12 L12 M12 S12">
      <Label text=""/>
      <Text text="Hello Kitty"/>
      <Input placeholder="Enter your email address" id="email" type="Email" value="{confirm>/email}" liveChange="onHandleLiveChangeEmail"/>
      <Button type="Accept" enabled="{confirm>/enable}" text="Hello" press=".handlePressAuthorization" width="100%" />
    </l:Grid>
  </FlexBox>
</Page>
```

Unfortunately, I could not figure out where the differences are except App 1 runs with Flexible Column Layout.

Both apps are hosted on GitHub:

- https://github.com/softshipper/app1
- https://github.com/softshipper/app2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App 1 has `sapUiSizeCompact` in the class list of `<body>` (see [`index.html` at line 34](https://github.com/softshipper/app1/blob/42e44ca6be14a816a296f04235f08daf0fa1840d/webapp/index.html#L34)).

App 2 doesn't have it, in which case the default density class is applied (`sapUiSizeCozy`).

---

For more information and other density options, see the step [Content Density](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/d935dbf196d34997bf1ac42ac3e81579) from the walkthrough as well as the corresponding [topic](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/e54f729da8e3405fae5e4fe8ae7784c1) from the documentation.